# Static fields in a base class and derived classes

Tags: c#, static, scope

In an `abstract` base class if we have some `static` fields then what happens to them ?

Is their scope the classes which inherit from this base class or just the type from which it is inheriting (each subclass has it's own copy of the `static` field from the `abstract` base class)?

Comment: BTW, the fact that the base class is `abstract` is a red herring; it doesn't matter if the base class is `abstract` or not, the behavior @Marc Gravell points out is the same.

Comment: @casperOne: I was looking for something like `TypeLocal<T>` as we have `ThreadLocal<T>` so any object of that type would be `static` in it's corresponding `subclass`.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`static` members are entirely specific to the ***declaring*** class; subclasses do not get separate copies. The only exception here is generics; if an open generic type declares static fields, the field is specific to that exact ***combination*** of type arguments that make up the closed generic type; i.e. `Foo<int>` would have separate static fields to `Foo<string>`, assuming the fields are defined on `Foo<T>`.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Sorry man, you and @Jon Skeet taught me to be pedantic; you meant to say "type arguments" as opposed to "static arguments". =)  Hope all is well across the pond.

Comment: The how to declare a unique variable for all instances (per type) from `base class` ?

Comment: @Xaqron: You can't, you would have to redeclare the static member you want on each derived class.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Being even *more* pedantic, it's casp **e** rOne, not casp **a** rOne =)

Comment: @casperOne - indeed; I blame iPod; it doesn't make things easy ;p For the record, I know the spelling - 'twas just a typo

Comment: It would be useful to have an access modifiers that allow that.

Answer (score 20):

As pointed out in other answer, the base class static field will be shared between all the subclasses. If you need a separate copy for each final subclass, you can use a static dictionary with a subclass name as a key:

```
class Base
{
    private static Dictionary<string, int> myStaticFieldDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public int MyStaticField
    {
        get
        {
            return myStaticFieldDict.ContainsKey(this.GetType().Name)
                   ? myStaticFieldDict[this.GetType().Name]
                   : default(int);
        }

        set
        {
            myStaticFieldDict[this.GetType().Name] = value;
        }
    }

    void MyMethod()
    {
        MyStaticField = 42;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code illustrates that the static member's value is shared among the instantiation of the abstract generic of the same type. Like in the example below all instantiations with generic type 'int' would share one static value, all 'string's another value. I was initially thinking that it would be shared among all instantiation agnostic to the generic type, but turned out that's not the case.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

abstract class AbstractGeneric<T>
{
    private static int sharedCounter = 0;

    public AbstractGeneric()
    {
        sharedCounter++;
    }
    
    public int GetCounterValue()
    {
        return sharedCounter;
    }
}

class GenInt : AbstractGeneric<int> {}
class GenInt2 : AbstractGeneric<int> {}
class GenStr : AbstractGeneric<string> {}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var instance1 = new GenInt();
        var instance2 = new GenStr();
        var instance3 = new GenInt2();
        var instance4 = new GenInt();

        Console.WriteLine(instance1.GetCounterValue()); // Output: 3
        Console.WriteLine(instance2.GetCounterValue()); // Output: 1
        Console.WriteLine(instance3.GetCounterValue()); // Output: 3
        Console.WriteLine(instance4.GetCounterValue()); // Output: 3
    }
}
```