# Why doesn't accessing a static member in a derived class trigger derived static constructor?

Tags: c#, static

I have a set of classes which should all have a static string member. Let's call it TABLENAME. The base class `ClassA<T>`, a templated class, for all of these classes has a protected static string member  called `TABLENAME`. Because of how dotnet handles static members for templated classes, each derived class gets its own instance of the static member. In addition, each class has it's own static constructor which sets `TABLENAME`. So far so good.

The issue I'm having is twofold.

1. Subclasses of `ClassA` appear to be able to access `TABLENAME` for other subclasses. i.e. `ClassAB` can reference `ClassAC.TABLENAME`.
2. Accessing `ClassAC.TABLENAME` from `ClassAB` does not trigger the static constructor in `ClassAC`.

Are there any good patterns for giving a set of classes a set of static members where each derived class has it's own set of values, and there is no way to access these values before they have been set.

Right now I can get around the issue by adding a non-static method to the base class called `Tablename()`, which returns the static string member `TABLENAME`. In the cases where `ClassAB` needs access to the `TABLENAME` from `ClassAC`, I can create an instance of `ClassAC` and call `Tablename()`. This will trigger the static constructor of `ClassAC`. I don't like this solution because you can accidentally access `ClassAC.TABLENAME` directly, which will return null, since it does not trigger static constructor for `ClassAC`.

The reason I want a set of static members is that I don't want to initialize these fields more than once per derived class.

Thoughts, ideas?

Comment: NB: "Templated" is a C++ term. C# has "Generics", i.e. a "generic" class, which is subtly different.

Comment: "*Accessing `ClassAC.TABLENAME` from `ClassAB` does not trigger the static constructor in `ClassAC`.*" -- [are you sure about that?](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUHqAUwHcACAYQBsBDAZ1oEEAhACgEoA6AFUNuHYDcePKgDMpDBRr0GAHi4A+PAG88pdRPGpMANgmYADKS7MAMgFEAcgwCy5obg2k1G7Xqp1G7F+tWOnrpgAnCwARB4ypADGUcAA9mChbA4BGiZMFtZ2pAC8pKEAZnFxoSkaAL54lfi4YhLoUp7MpCCNMrIAllDASrh+Tm5tjKxsPqT9qfoh4dLD0bEJraGkiMZmVrbmyWPVY3WoACzGvPyj/r5jA8Es6Zmb2+ek1eVAA) A [mcve] would be very useful to figure out exactly what you're doing and seeing.

Comment: OP, it's likely that you're doing something wrong, but I can't tell what because you didn't show any code. Show your code please.

Comment: Is `TABLENAME` private or public/protected?

Answer (score 0):

By design, the static members of the **Declaring Class** are shared amongst all the subclasses. So your `TABLENAME` static member in `ClassA` will be shared amongst all its sub-classes. (Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5851501/17985195)

---

To address your issue,

> The reason I want a set of static members is that I don't want to initialize these fields more than once per derived class.

You can make use of **Auto-Properties** with an initial value.

So in your derived class, set your member like:

```
public string TABLENAME { get; set; } = "Initial Table Name"; // C# 6 or higher
```

This way, when that subclass is instantiated, your `TABLENAME` field is initialized with `"Initial Table Name"` and you can make that unique to everyone of your subclasses, which is essentially what you wanted.